# Fileinfo not working in Xampp v3.2.1

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, fileinfo

hey i want install a portal(CMS) on xampp but its give me a some error about file info and cant install it if anybody can help me to fix it please anwser 
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbZtN.jpg)

Comment: This question is better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to your xampp php.ini and uncomment the line :

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

and dont forget to restart apache

Comment: thank you so much :) its work it nice now again thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the [fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) PHP extension.

On xampp you basically need to edit the *php.ini* file and uncomment the line which enables the extension. You should find the *php.ini* file in the xampp folder.

Replace:

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

with:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Comment: thank you so much :) its work it nice now again thank you